# How to check if string contains specific hex value

Tags: string, bash

Im having trouble with a BASH script

I have a variable that gets populated with a string from at curl command, this string is often two words with a space. The space is not \x20 but \x0A in hex, which results in a carriage return which i would like to counter.

I have no control of the returned string as is gets the data from Google

Is there a simple way of checking if the string variable contains \x0A hex ?
And is it possible to manipulate the string, changing \x0A value to \x20

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: you could use `tr '\n' ' '` to replace it with a space, e.g., `var=$(echo -en "$var" | tr '\n' ' ')`

Comment: @ewcz amazing, this just did the work, it works like a charm, thanks ;)

Comment: my pleasure... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use bash's built-in parameter expansion to convert all white space to plain spaces:

```
a=$' a\rb\nc'
$ echo "$a"
ba
c
$ a="${a//[[:space:]]/ }"
```

On other shells you can use `tr` to do the same, at the expense of calling external processes and creating subshells:

```
$ a=$(printf '%s' "$a" | tr '[:space:]' ' ')
```

In either case, the result is:

```
$ echo "$a"
 a b c
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a simple way of checking if the string variable contains \x0A hex ? And is it possible to manipulate the string, changing \x0A value to \x20

Yes and yes.

As Tom suggests, you can manipulate the string using parameter expansion in bash or `tr` in any shell.

If you first want to check whether a string *contains* a special character, bash's built in test capabilities will do the job.

```
$ s=$'a\rb\r'; [[ $s == *$'\n'* ]] && echo "Yes"
$ s=$'a\rb\n'; [[ $s == *$'\n'* ]] && echo "Yes"
Yes
```